# Encoding trouble when writing in database (Perl)

Tags: mysql, perl, encoding, character-encoding, dbi

In Perl **v5.10.1**, I try to read a file and store strings in a database.
Problems arise when strings contain accents and exotic characters.

On my CentOS 6, the 'locale' command indicates:
**LANG=en_US.UTF-8**

My DB is **MySQL**, the field I'm writing on is varchar(64) **utf8_unicode_ci**.

I run my test through a Putty console, set with Window > Translation > Remote character set: UTF8, though printed characters are garbled, but this is not the main problem.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use DBI;

# A test string
my $test = 'é';
print "- 1: $test\n";

# First string in my file, containing a single 'é'
my $string = '';
open(my $fh, '<', 'myFile');
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  $string = $line;
  last;
}
close $fh;
print "- 2: $string\n";


# Writing test string and first string in DB
my $dbistring = 'DBI:mysql:database=xxxx;host=xxxx;port=xxxx';
my $socket = DBI->connect($dbistring, 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
my $cmd = 'UPDATE Strings SET string="'.$test.'" WHERE id=1';
my $request = $socket->prepare($cmd);
$request->execute();
$cmd = 'UPDATE Strings SET string="'.$string.'" WHERE id=2';
$request = $socket->prepare($cmd);
$request->execute();
```

The prints are as follows:

- 1: ▒
- 2: ▒

In my DB table, fields end up as:

- id 1: Ã©
- id 2: Ã©

To avoid a possible double-encoding from Perl string concatenation, I tried:

```
$string = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $string);
```

giving me the same result.
Same if I indicate '<:encoding(UTF-8)' when opening the file.

I am much confused, as my process chain seems to be all set in UTF8. Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: At the very least, you need to add `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` to add an encoding/decoding layer to STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR and to files opened in scope.

Answer (score 1):

This [valuable article](http://blog.thewebsitepeople.org/2012/06/perl-default-to-utf-8-encoding/) provided the solution:

The problem arises during the communication between DBI and the DB, and is solved by adding the **mysql_enable_utf8** flag during the connection:

```
DBI->connect($dbistring, 'xxxx', 'xxxx', { mysql_enable_utf8 => 1 });
```

Comment: I forgot it effectively does `SET NAMES utf8` when passed to `connect`, in addition to the decoding effect obtained from `$dbh->{mysql_enable_utf8} = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

**Some issues in Perl**

```
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:".$dsn, $user, $password, {
       PrintError => 0,
       RaiseError => 1,
       mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,  # Switch to UTF-8 for communication and decode.
});
# or {mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1} if using utf8mb4
```

**Mojibake**

See "Mojibake" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for other issues to check on.